# Listen to Mongoose Schema.pre('remove')

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

From [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-pre) looks like it is possible to listen to this hook to remove any orphan document. Truth is that I can't get this lister to work. Either using the default method:

```js
MySchema.pre('remove', function(
  next: () => void
) {
  log('Will remove item: ' + this._id);
  next();
});
```

Nor by setting the option `query` to `true`.

```js
(MySchema as any).pre('remove', { query: true, document: false }, function(
  next: () => void
) {
  log('Will remove item: ' + this._id);
  next();
});
```

Note that to remove the document I use `model.findByIdAndRemove()`, but I tried also using `doc.remove()`

```js
const doc = await model.findById(id);
doc.remove(() => {
  log('REMOVED DOC');
});
```

I'm with version `5.7.13`. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`pre('remove', { query: true, document: false })` is for [`Query#remove()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-remove), not `findByIdOrRemove()` or `Document#remove()`.

```js
await model.remove({ _id: id });
```